# What is the easiest way to find a folder by it containing a string but deleting a folder beneath it? (BATCH)

Tags: batch-file

So I'm trying to make a .bat file that finds a folder by a string, the string being "version", within a directory, and if the folder contains that string in the name, then I delete a folder beneath it called "textures". Effectively, the directory for deletion would be -

Folder found by string in name\PlatformContent\pc\textures

The directory would be

I'm quite new to Batch as I'm normally only a LUA programmer, so it's a bit confusing for me, and I can seem to work out the easiest way of doing this.

```
for /D %%i in (dir /b /s "directory" findstr /i "version") do (
    del %%i\PlatformContent\pc\textures
)
```

This is probably stupidly wrong, so I apologise in advance
If anyone could help that'd be really greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `for /f %%i in ('dir /Ad /b /s *version*') do ...`. Let the dir command do some of the work. See `help for` and `help dir`. I would try the dir command manually first, and make sure it produced the list of directory paths you're looking for.

Comment: You shouldn't need `findstr` for what you've described.

Answer (score 0):

See `help for`, `help dir` `help rd`. The `dir` command can do all of the filtering for you with `/Ad` and an appropriate glob string.

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /Ad /b /s *version*') do (rd /s /q "%%i\PlatformContent\pc\textures")
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you do not use the `Del`/`Erase` command for directories, you use the `RmDir`/`RD` command.

You did not provide us with a proper example of a directory structure which holds a directory somewhere within it containing the string `version`. However, I've taken a best guess that this is for `Roblox`, and provided that for you too, *(so there is nothing in the answer below which requires modification)*:

```sh
@For /D %%G In ("%LocalAppData%\Roblox\Versions\version-*"
) Do @If Exist "%%~fG\PlatformContent\pc\textures\" (
    RD /S /Q "%%~fG\PlatformContent\pc\textures"
)
```

However, there may be more than one `version-*` directory, and you might want to remove the stated directory from only the most recently created, or even most recently written to, *(please change `/T:C` to `/T:W` below, if the latter)*. For that you should use a `For /F` loop, with the `Dir` command to order by date, newest first, *`/O:-D`*:

```sh
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
    'Dir /B /A:D /O:-D /T:C "%LocalAppData%\Roblox\Versions\version-*"') Do @(
    If Exist "%LocalAppData%\Roblox\Versions\%%G\PlatformContent\pc\textures\" (
        RD /S /Q "%LocalAppData%\Roblox\Versions\%%G\PlatformContent\pc\textures"
    )
    GoTo Next
)
:Next
```